# How to specify only one address for authors in BioMed Central LaTeX template?

Tags: templates, addresses, affiliation

I am using [the BioMed Central LaTeX template](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) to typesetting a manuscript. In specifying the address for the authors, I found that the template failed to handle the single address case, i.e.: when directly using the lines given in the original templates, which specifies two different addresses for the authors, it works:

```
\address[id=aff1]{%                             % unique id
  \orgname{Department of Zoology, Cambridge},   % university, etc
  \street{Waterloo Road},                       % address
  \postcode{}                                   % post or zip code
  \city{London},                                % city
  \cny{UK}                                      % country
}
\address[id=aff2]{%
  \orgname{Marine Ecology Department, Institute of Marine Sciences Kiel},
  \street{D\"{u}sternbrooker Weg 20},
  \postcode{24105}
  \city{Kiel},
  \cny{Germany}
}
```

When commented one of the two addresses,

```
\address[id=aff1]{%                             % unique id
  \orgname{Department of Zoology, Cambridge},   % university, etc
  \street{Waterloo Road},                       % address
  \postcode{}                                   % post or zip code
  \city{London},                                % city
  \cny{UK}                                      % country
}
%\address[id=aff2]{%
%  \orgname{Marine Ecology Department, Institute of Marine Sciences Kiel},
%  \street{D\"{u}sternbrooker Weg 20},
%  \postcode{24105}
%  \city{Kiel},
%  \cny{Germany}
%}
```

and removed the corresponding unique id of the address in the author field, i.e., to change the line:

```
addressref={aff1,aff2},
```

to

```
addressref={aff1},
```

the superscripts for the first author's name is replaced by "??", and the ones (used to be "1" or "2") for each author's name are disappeared.

Comment: I tested that template and it works as expected. LaTeXmk did quite a few runs, which might explain why the OP sees question marks. Either they updated the template, or it did work all the time. Nobody knows. Since an answer *Right now, it works* doesn't help anybody, i vote to close as unclear.